# Function for creating combinations in R

Tags: r, loops, syntax, combinations

I need to create combinations using 'n' variables with a minimum value of 5 & maximum of 80, with a difference of x between them and the sum of values for each combination should be equal to 100.

Comment: Please tag with the language being used.

Comment: You seem to be mostly there (except for the difference). What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: right now it it limited to m1,m2,m3,m4. what i'm looking for is a function where i dont have to type these as 'm' increases, but more like a range say if m is 10, then 1-10, rather than typing m1,m2,....m10 in this code

Comment: more like a loop function!

Comment: @SagarRamsinghani Gotcha, see my reply.

Answer (score 0):

For *n* variables, you need to pass a variable amount of parameters to `expand.grid`. You can use [`do.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html) for this:

```
combs = do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(seq(from = 5, to = 80, by = 5)), n))
```

If you want to customise the names, you need to assign them separately (via `setNames`). For instance, to get the names `m1` … `mn`, use:

```
values = rep(list(seq(from = 5, to = 80, by = 5)), n)
names = paste0('m', seq_len(n))
combs = do.call(expand.grid, setNames(values, names))
```

Furthermore, I wouldn’t store the total in the same data.frame — use a separate variable:

```
total = rowSums(combs)
```

… But this is actually not even necessary.

Put together in a function definition:

```
my_combs = function (n, from, to, by, total) {
    values = rep(list(seq(from, to, by)), n)
    names = paste0('m', seq_len(n))
    combs = do.call(expand.grid, setNames(values, names))
    combs[rowSums(combs) == total, ]
}
```

And you call it (for instance) like this:

```
result = my_combs(n = 2, from = 5, to = 80, by = 5, total = 100)
```

Which yields:

```
> result
    m1 m2
64  80 20
79  75 25
94  70 30
109 65 35
124 60 40
139 55 45
154 50 50
169 45 55
184 40 60
199 35 65
214 30 70
229 25 75
244 20 80
```

Comment: Awesome ! how do i get to print all the combinations, only a few are showing, the rest are getting omitted ?

Comment: @SagarRamsinghani It prints all combinations. You are probably getting confused by the row numbering. The subsetting we are performing in the last row doesn’t touch the row names (which are numbers). So if we filter out the first row for instance, the resulting table will have a first row whose name/number is different.

Comment: not sure where i am going wrong :                                                dynamic = function (4, 5, 80, 5, 100) {
  combs = do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(seq(5, 80, 5)), 4))
  comb_total = rowSums(combs)
  combs[comb_total == 100, ]
}

Comment: @SagarRamsinghani You’re getting confused between *defining* a function and *calling* a function there. See updated answer.

Comment: You don't need do.call -- expand.grid can take lists, so just `expand.grid(rep(list(seq(...)), n))`

Comment: Thanks, Konrad ! The problem is happening when I'm increasing n & by, it is not printing due to memory constraints, is there a way i can create a syntax that takes care of it in the function itself ?

Comment: See this -                                                                                                  comb <- function (n, from, to, by) {
combs <-do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(seq(from, to, by)), n))
  combs$total <- rowSums(combs)
  comb1<-combs[combs$total == 100, ]
  comb1
}                                                                                                    combs(6, 5, 80, 1)

Comment: any thoughts on how i can fix this to be able to generate all results ?